# Web Api Controller with two POST Method

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api

In CardsController, I have two post method written as below. I tried with  /api/cards/card or /api/cards/cardlist and get exception message such as

> **"Multiple actions were found that match the request:
>   \r\nSystem.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage PostValue(Card) on type**
>   WebApiService.Controllers.CardsController\r\nSystem.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage
>   PostValue(CardList) on type
>   WebApiService.Controllers.CardsController",   "ExceptionType":
>   "System.InvalidOperationException",   "StackTrace": "   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsyncInternal(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"

```
<HttpPost()>
<ActionName("card")>
Public Function PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal value As Card_REQ.Card) As HttpResponseMessage

<HttpPost()>
<ActionName("cardlist")>
Public Function PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal value As Cards_REQ.CardList) As HttpResponseMessage
```

In the Web.Config is configured as below.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( _
        name:="DefaultApi", _
        routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}", _
        defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional} _
    )

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( _
       name:="DefaultApiWithAction", _
       routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
       defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional} _
   )
```

Comment: did you try changing routes order? First "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"  and then "api/{controller}/{id}" ? Yes, change Web.Config and put first the route with more params.

Comment: @Mate Thanks alot. Can you post your comment as answer. Need to mark your answer. 

Erm, why is the routes order is causing the error message?
Is the service still RESTFUL when i include the action name in the routes? ( /api/cards/card or /api/cards/cardlist)

Comment: Yes, but why not use  /api/cards/list or method GET and invoke /api/cards  ?

Comment: Ahhh, was not aware of the action name>< Thanks @Mate

Comment: I'm glad to be of help. Check this guide http://blog.mwaysolutions.com/2014/06/05/10-best-practices-for-better-restful-api/  ( cars examples too! )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Web.Config and put first the route with more params

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( _
       name:="DefaultApiWithAction", _
       routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
       defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional} _
   )

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( _
        name:="DefaultApi", _
        routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}", _
        defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional} _
    )
```

first pattern to match against the URL will be action that handles the request. [Check Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#Anchor_8)

Comment: When i created a new method PUT, i must defined action name(eg: cards) for the method and able to route with /api/cards/cards/1234567890.

Is it possible to route with route with /api/cards/1234567890

Comment: try setting parameter name as "id"  Public Function PutValue(<FromBody()> ByVal **id** as Integer) ...

Comment: Yeah, i put <HttpPut()>
        Public Function PutValue(ByVal Id As String, <FromBody()> ByVal value As Cards_PUT_REQ) As HttpResponseMessage and get message details "No action was found on the controller 'Cards' that matches the name '1234567890'."  It only works when i define action name for this PUT method

Comment: Ok, I saw your other question, let's continue there